# How to be authenticated in both cross domain websites

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have 2 websites. One of them is "Main Website". And I have website with "User Preferences". How to implement the logic that when we already logged in "Main Website", and when we click on the link with "User Preferences" website we will be authenticated in this website as well.

What is the best solution to do it.

Comment: Maybe it should be like SSO. But not sure how can I do it with two websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you:

- User visits site A
- User logs into site A
- Site A create a token in the DB for the user
- Site A encrypts the token using something like AES
- Site A redirects the user to Site B with the encrypted token in the URL (or creates an iframe)

E.g.

```
www.site-b.com/remote/login?token=DSJABDUISA65ASA65ASD$#A&DE7t8%SARD$A%AS*%^DR76daBDD$#A&DE7t8%SARD$A%ASA65ASD$#A&DE7t8%SARD$A%AS*%^DR76daBD*%^DR76daBDsFA%vd%Bd
```

- Site B decrypts, validates, and deletes the token
- Site B automatically logs the user in
- Site B redirects the user back to site A (or kills the iframe)

Answer (score 0):

> To configure forms authentication across applications, you set
>   attributes of the forms and machineKey sections of the Web.config file
>   to the same values for all applications that are participating in
>   shared forms authentication.
>
> The following example shows the Authentication section of a Web.config
>   file. Unless otherwise noted, the **name**, **protection**, **path**,
>   **validationKey**, **validation**, **decryptionKey**, and **decryption** attributes
>   must be identical across all applications. Similarly, the encryption
>   and validation key values and the encryption scheme and validation
>   scheme used for authentication tickets (cookie data) must be the same.
>   If the settings do not match, authentication tickets cannot be shared.
>   For information about how to generate values for the validationKey and
>   decryptionKey attributes, see How To: Configure MachineKey in ASP.NET
>   2.0. (This topic applies to ASP.NET version 2.0 and to later versions.)

More reading at [Forms Authentication Across Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)